# My SQLite database is not recognized : "no such table myapp_onemodel"

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have set up a Django website (1.7.3) with Python 3 on my VPS (Ubuntu12.04, Apache2.2) with mod_wsgi. 
I have this following error when trying to get on mywebsite page that involves the database :

```
OperationalError at /myapp/
no such table: myapp_category
Request Method:GET
Request URL: http://mywebsite.com/myapp/
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: no such table: myapp_category
Exception Location: /opt/.virtualenvs/mysite_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 485
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version:3.2.3
Python Path: ['/opt/.virtualenvs/mysite_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py3.2.egg',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/mysite_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg',
 '/var/www/mywebsite',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/mysite_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.2',
 '/usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

My settings.py on my server regarding the database is the following :

```
import os    
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    DATABASES = {
        'default':{
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        }
    }
```

1. I ran `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` (I have only one app in my website) and `python manage.py migrate` successfully. (I also remove migrations/ folder and mydatabase file and began anew to two first commands to run the migrations, also successfully).
2. I checked the 'mydatabase' file exists.
3. I put the right permissions on `mydatabase` file.
   But the error stays the same, as if the database does not exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current dir of your WSGI app is different from your project dir.  Add the `home` argument to your `WSGIDaemonProcess` description